# Existe forma de setar width especificado no html como o max-width deste elemento no css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

O problema é o seguinte: Eu tenho a seguinte html:

```
<div class="page-left-col">
    <p>
        <img src="/localhost/Department%20Pages/Communications/News/LearnStorm%20Rally.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 20px auto;" width="400">
    </p>
</div>
```

E no css está assim:

```
div.page-left-col img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Eu gostaria de pegar esse width 400 (exemplo) que está no html e dizer para o meu css que esse width será o max-width, pois preciso deixar esse width como 100% mesmo para que ele se adapte ao tamanho das janelas. Não posso deixar 400 fixo, pois dependendo da nova postagem, essa imagem pode ser setada com qualquer outro tamanho no width. O que preciso saber é se existe uma forma de dizer no css que o max-width é o width que tiver no html.

Comment: Usa DOM/Jquery.

Comment: Ola, Infelizmente não percebi a sua questão. Esta a tentar dizer se ao carregar a pagina o width é 200px e se o utilizador maximizar a janela deverá ficar a 200px? Ou o que pretende é ser sempre 100% mas no maximo 400px?

Comment: Sempre 100% mas no máximo 400px, @TiagoGomes. Na verdade, nao especificamente 400, por isso que não quero por max-width:400px. Pois alí pode vir qualquer valor. O que quero é sempre 100% e máximo o valor que vem no width do HTML

Comment: Já tentou um max-width: 100%

Comment: Sim @Bruno. Não funciona

Comment: Não teria como voce mostrar uma página de exemplo, acho que ficaria muito mais facil de te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em css não é possivel ir buscar a informação.
Pode fazer em jquery.: (é generalizado pode causar lentidão)

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){//executa quando terminar de carregar a pagina
         $('img').each(function(){//passa em todas as imagens (aqui pode fazer mais filtros coloquei generico)

            if ($(this).is('[width]')){
               $(this)
                  .css({
                     'max-width':$(this).attr('width')+(($(this).attr('width')).indexOf('px')<0?'px':''),
                     'width':'100%'
                  })
                  .removeAttr('width')
               ;//transforma o wdth como maximo e atualiza para ficar responsive
            }
         });   
   });
<script>
```

Os códigos anteriores não estavam a funcionar porque o width da imagem não tem unidade, portanto coloquei como px para funcionar.

O exemplo no jsfiddle.:
<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/9oqy5Lby/</strike>
<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/9oqy5Lby/2/</strike>
<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/9oqy5Lby/3/</strike>
<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/9oqy5Lby/4/</strike>
https://jsfiddle.net/9oqy5Lby/12/

Comment: Se for por este caminho deverá mudar as tags da sua pergunta

Comment: Vou tentar usar sua solução. Ainda não consegui. O que quer dizer com "mudar as tags da pergunta"?

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer. Mudei as tags

Comment: Fiz o teste mas infelizmente a função não está pegando o valor que está dentro do width do HTML, mas calcula o width que está no momento... no caso, no HTML está com width 400 mas por conta do width:100% do css, o width que o elemento está é 620 mesmo tendo 400 no HTML. Sendo assim o código que vc passou pega o valor 620 e seta como max-width... mas não pega o 400 que está no HTML

Comment: Será que tem uma forma de ao invés de ser 'max-width':$(this).width(), receber ao invés de $(this).width() pegar o atributo width que está naquele html?

Comment: Estava a dormir. Vou já corrigir

Comment: Pois é, imaginei que fosse funcionar fazendo isso 'max-width':$(this).attr('width'), mas infelizmente eu tentei isso e não funciona. Quando faço isso nenhuma max-width é setada. Só a width 100% :(

Comment: As imagens têm de ter o atributo width como tem no exemplo.

Comment: Coloquei um if para só manipular a imagem que tiver o atributo

Comment: Isso é muto estranho. A imagem tem o atributo, como você viu. Está aí no exemplo assim como no código. Mas executei agora o código que me passou e deu esse erro, como se a variável width nao existisse:
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)

Comment: Será que não seria algum problema no filtro para achar a imagem?

Comment: É fazer as coisas sem testar. Corrigido

Comment: Agradeço muito toda a sua ajuda. Infelizmente a correção não encontra o elemento. Não chega a fazer nenhuma modificação. Desculpe tomar tanto seu tempo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39274/discussion-between-tiago-gomes-and-araujo-filho).

Answer (score 1):

Teria como manipular usando javascript. Da forma que vocês está querendo, acho pouco provável. 
Por que não retira o width do HTML e mantem apenas o do CSS. Assim ele terá sempre o valor de 100%.

Comment: Não tenho como retirar do HTML pois esse HTML é gerado dinamicamente. Eu não sei como eu poderia resolver com javascript

Comment: nao pode mexer no codigo php?

Answer (score 0):

Com CSS:

```
div.page-left-col img {
    max-width: 400px !important; /* isto deve-se sobrepor aos styles inline */
    width:100% !important; /* isto deve-se sobrepor aos styles inline */
}
```

Comment: Olá Miguel. Eu não quero setar o max-width como 400. No meu html pode vir qualquer valor dentro do width. O html é gerado dinamicamente por usuários quando fazem novas postagens no sistema. O que quero é que o max-width pegue o valor que está já no html para que as imagens nunca fiquem maiores do que o que está setado no HTML

Comment: Ha, percebi... A melhor seria com Javascript/jQuery. Teria de mudar as tags da sua pergunta

Comment: Não percebo. Eu iria dar a mesma resposta sempre 100% o maximo 400px. Pode exclarecer melhor sobre "No meu html pode vir qualquer valor dentro do width" o html é fixo não é dinâmico. Como fica dinâmico?

Comment: Percebi, desculpe, não tinha reparado que tinha a width definida inline (`style=...`) no html

Comment: OK. Como é que é gerado o código? Em vez colocar width="400" insira dentro do style max-width:400; é possivel?

Comment: Sim creio, que sendo assim essa solução é melhor. Sim dá

Comment: Infelizmente não é possível. Esse html é gerado por outro serviço. São postagens feitas em uma caixa de diálogo pelos usuários do sistema. Quando eles colocam uma imagem, eles setam o tamanho. Mas no html é setado assim. O que tenho que fazer é uma forma de meu css pegar esse valor e por como max-width

Comment: Editei a minha resposta, tente dessa maneira

Comment: Olá Miguel. Acho que você não entendeu. Eu não quero que 400 seja um valor fixo, isso foi apenas um exemplo. Alí pode vir qualquer valor, pois esse width no HTML é gerado automaticamente pelo sistema. Eu quero que o max-width pegue o valor de width que vier no HTML não importando ele qual seja

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, seu servidor gera o HTML dinamicamente e preenche o width.

```
<div class="page-left-col">
    <p>
        <img src="https://s.zkcdn.net/Advertisers/54f16e366c5a405e8b169d56a243d215.png" style="display: block; margin: 20px auto;max-width: 400px">
    </p>
</div>
```

Desse jeito a imagem não vai crescer mais que o tamanho original dela e você continua conseguindo setar o max-width pelo servidor.

Comment: Sim, meu servidor gera esse html. Mas por conta de eu ter meu css dizendo width: 100%; minha imagem cresce até onde a janela permite, ficando enorme! Tirando essa propriedade ela não cresce. Mas não posso tirar essa propriedade do meu css.

Comment: O max-width dentro do style tem prioridade maior que o width do CSS, então ela não vai crescer mais. Olha: https://jsfiddle.net/41efc7ny/

Comment: Eu entendo. Mas como eu falei, meu serviço gera esse html, não eu. É um outro serviço. Eu não tenho como editar o HTML que vai vir.